# How to determine proper capacitors to replace a battery for an Apple Magic Trackpad 2?

Tags: batteries, capacitor, electromagnetism, trace, apple

I have several Apple Magic Trackpad 2 devices and am finding that the batteries routinely go bad on these.  They swell and deform the trackpad such that it doesn't stay flat with the desk / tray surface and thus out of fear of fire, etc. I removed the battery from two of these that were bulging well beyond capacity.

Upon removing these batteries I found that with the devices plugged in they do still operate, BUT the magnetic impulse coil no longer functions to provide tactile (haptic) feedback.  It clearly needs the battery to act as a capacitor for a large enough electrical discharge to trigger the magnet for clicks / vibrations since the USB amperage is likely simply not powerful enough to provide this.

I prefer to operate these devices without batteries after this experience and basically losing hundreds of dollars since they are apparently out of warranty.

At this point I'd like to figure out how to spec and attach proper capacitors to these Trackpads in order to facilitate the haptic feedback engine's triggering.

Any thoughts on how would I go about ascertaining this?